# What is wrong with my trigger?

Tags: mysql-5.5

For reasons unknown to me,  the control flow doesnt reach "ITS CORRECT BUT PRIZE IS MONETARY" block, that corresponds to variable `bounty` not being `NULL`. I'm pretty confident that `SELECT Bounty FROM Questions WHERE QuestionID = NEW.QuestionID` must return `INT UNSIGNED`.

So, is my syntax wrong? Am I using some kind of bad IF condition?

The trigger code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2Cbq9YUZ)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CheckCorrect` AFTER INSERT ON `UserAnswers`    
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN    
DECLARE bounty INT UNSIGNED;  
SET bounty:=(SELECT `Bounty` FROM `Questions` WHERE `QuestionID` = 
 NEW.`QuestionID`);  
 IF (SELECT `IsCorrect` FROM `Answers` WHERE `AnswerID` = NEW.`AnswerID`)<>0 
THEN     // IF ITS CORRECT
  IF bounty IS NULL THEN    // FIELD `Bounty` being NULL means that a prize is set.
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `Prizes` WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID` AND `ClaimerID` IS NULL) THEN    //ANY SPARE
      BEGIN  
      UPDATE `Prizes` SET `ClaimerID` = NEW.`UserID` WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID` AND `ClaimerID` IS NULL ORDER BY              
             `PrizeID` LIMIT 1;  
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, "NEWPRIZE", NOW(), FALSE);  
      END;  
    ELSE    //IF NOT LEAVE A MESSAGE!
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, "NOPRIZE", NOW(), FALSE );  
    END IF;  
  ELSE     // ITS CORRECT BUT PRIZE IS MONETARY
    IF (SELECT `Budget` FROM `Questions` WHERE `QuestionID`=NEW.`QuestionID`)>bounty THEN  // DO WE HAVE ENOUGH BUDGET TO PAY?
      BEGIN  
      UPDATE `Questions` SET `Budget`=`Budget`-bounty WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID`;  
      UPDATE `Users` SET `Balance`=`Balance`+bounty WHERE `UserID`=NEW.`UserID`;  
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, CAST(bounty AS CHAR(50)), NOW(), FALSE);  
      END;  
    ELSE   // NO MORE MONEY, I'M AFRAID
     INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, "NOMONEY", 
 NOW(), FALSE );  
   END IF;  
  END IF;  
END IF;  
END;
```

Updated my code like so due to Jacob H's suggestion. No results.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER `CheckCorrect` AFTER INSERT ON `UserAnswers`    //CLAIM PRIZE AND NOTIFY!
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN    
DECLARE bounty INT UNSIGNED;   
SET bounty:=(SELECT `Bounty` FROM `Questions` WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID`);   
IF (SELECT `IsCorrect` FROM `Answers` WHERE `AnswerID` = NEW.`AnswerID`)<>0 THEN     // IF ITS CORRECT
   BEGIN   
  IF bounty IS NULL THEN    // IF ITS A PRIZE CLAIM IT
    BEGIN  
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `Prizes` WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID` AND `ClaimerID` IS NULL) THEN    //ANY SPARE PRIZES?
      BEGIN   
      UPDATE `Prizes` SET `ClaimerID` = NEW.`UserID` WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID` AND `ClaimerID` IS NULL ORDER BY `PrizeID` LIMIT 1;   
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, "NEWPRIZE", NOW(), FALSE);   
      END;   
    ELSE    //IF NOT LEAVE A MESSAGE!
      BEGIN   
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, "NOPRIZE", NOW(), FALSE );   
      END;   
    END IF;   
    END;  
  ELSE     // ITS CORRECT BUT PRIZE IS MONETARY
    BEGIN   
    IF (SELECT `Budget` FROM `Questions` WHERE `QuestionID`=NEW.`QuestionID`)>bounty THEN   
      BEGIN   
      UPDATE `Questions` SET `Budget`=`Budget`-bounty WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID`;   
      UPDATE `Users` SET `Balance`=`Balance`+bounty WHERE `UserID`=NEW.`UserID`;   
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`,CAST(bounty AS CHAR(50)), NOW(), FALSE);   
      END;   
    ELSE   
      BEGIN  
      INSERT INTO `Notifications` VALUES (NULL, NEW.`UserID`, "NOMONEY", NOW(), FALSE );   
      END;  
    END IF;   
    END;   
  END IF;   
  END   
END IF;   
END;
```

Comment: Can you nest an IF/THEN in MySQL without BEGIN/END? Maybe it's short-circuiting to "IF NOT LEAVE A MESSAGE!"? Have you tried reading the bounty value at execution time?

Comment: To clarify: You've got entries in `Notifications` where the third column's value is "NEWPRIZE" and "NOPRIZE", but none where the value is "NOMONEY" or a monetary value? And, the trigger is not generating any errors? ON general principles, you might want to explicitly cast `bounty` from an integer to a character value when you go to set that third column to that value. I'm not necessarily thinking that's the problem, but it's a good idea in principle.

Comment: @RDFozz Notification table contains only "NOPRIZE" messages for occasions that were supposed to spawn INT or "NOMONEY" results. So I concluded that control flow does not reach this block at all. Yeah, I can try casting `bounty` but not doing it did not raise any errors. Will correct that now.

Comment: @JacobH Umm.. I will try and remove `BEGIN/END;` as well as one instruction. Maybe it will work, but I don't see how it can help. 

Also, I'm not sure how can I ping `bounty` value during runtime. Will google how to do that.

Comment: No I mean ADD it. Not remove it. In your nested IF/THEN statement. Sorry that was a bit confusing.

Comment: @JacobH nope, no result. See question for updated code that I tried. Or did you have some other update in mind?

Comment: I would assume @JacobH was suggested that all `IF ... THEN` and `ELSE` code blocks be designated with `BEGIN` and `END`, including `IF (SELECT \`IsCorrect\` ...` and `IF bounty IS NULL`. Also, you might clarify - "No result" doesn't imply quite the same thing as "no change".

Comment: Did not help. Heck. xD I guess I'll triple check other parts of my program. I have no idea why this does not work.

Comment: If all else fails, consider (for testing purposes) adding entries to `Notifications` after every `BEGIN`, so you know exactly where you got, and what `bounty` is set to.

Comment: Thank you guys for your concern, I managed to fix it and the answer will surprise you. I think xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was change

```
SET bounty:=(SELECT `Bounty` FROM `Questions` WHERE `QuestionID` = 
NEW.`QuestionID`);
```

to

```
SELECT `Bounty` INTO bountyvar FROM `Questions` WHERE `QuestionID` = NEW.`QuestionID`;
```

and it started working... Why though xD

Some light can be shed on that from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error): apparently some versions of MySQL just don't like some variations of syntax. Oh well. I'm glad this is over. I'm tired.

Comment: I didn't know just beating around a bush like that could yield any results or I would have done it sooner. Hell.